# Force user reauthentication on symfony

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

I'm developping a website with a member area and user levels. admin members can access to an area where they can view, add and change some sensitive data.

To add a protection layer on this group of pages, i'd like to ask users their login and password before accesing the home page of the restricted area even if they are already logged in.

How can i do that ? in the symfony doc, i haven't found anything about a second authentication of the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for here is IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED vs IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY.  If you have remember me functionality you can set the session to expire after 30 minutes to an hour (or whatever time interval you think is ok)  When the session times out, in admin areas, if you check for is authenticated fully they'll be asked to login, if they visit any place with lower bar (e.g. is authenticated remembered) they'll still appear logged in.  This is basically what amazon does when you try access your user settings page.  Sure you're logged in and can add stuff to your cart, but once you try and access your sensitive data, you must re-login.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid a second authentication... I is better to work with restriction layers (user roles)... the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) already provides all the needed functionality

Comment: i already use user roles but i wanted to add a second authentication because as people can store their password in the browser, everybody whitn an access to the computer can log in with admin rights and an access to the sensitive data. Also, if an admin go on a public computer and forget to log out, the next user will have access to the restricted area without having to enter the password.

Comment: You can set the auth-token to be invalid after a certain timeout... because with a second login layer you will have the same issues that you are taking about if you are just nesting them

Comment: the second authentication will prevent the second issue (user forget to log out) and if i put `autocomplete="off"` on the second form fields, the browser should not prefill the form

Comment: autocomplete="off" will not prevent anyone to login with the stored credentials...  As it says it just prevents autocompletion

Comment: oh i thought stored credentials were seen as autocompletions